# Is $\sum_{i=1}^n [-1-x_i e^{-\alpha}]=0$ solvable analytically or numerically for $\alpha$?

Tags: numerical-methods

Is $\sum_{i=1}^n  [-1-x_i e^{-\alpha}]=0$ solvable analytically or numerically for $\alpha$?

My own interpretation is that if one tries to solve the above by taking the logarithm, then one is not able to get rid of the logarithm, but rather it has to be approximated numerically.

Is this correct?

Comment: Exact solution ...$\alpha=- \ln \left(\frac{-n}{\sum x_i} \right)$ 
... the moment you plug values in, you will have an approximate solution (unless you are really lucky).

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit But there's no logarithm of negative number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually totally straight-forward
$$\begin{align}
0 &= \sum_{i=1}^n(-1-x_ie^{-\alpha}) \\
 &=-n-e^{-\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i
\end{align}$$
This can be explicitly solved for alpha:
$$ \alpha = \log\left(\frac{-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)$$

Comment: But there's no logarithm of negative number?

Comment: @mavavilj If you take a look at the second expression you will notice that $n$ is positive and $e^{-\alpha}$. If you rewrite this expression to $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i = -\frac{n}{e^{-\alpha}}$ you will notice that the sum is negative. This means that argument of the logarithm function will always be positive.